# Why String method substring() is not in camelCase in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

As per Java's standard we should follow CamelCase. But why String's method substring() is not in camelCase ? Is it for any specific reason or just an mistake from the initial days ?

Comment: As the two answers say, it's a single word. Not just in Java, either; wikipedia agrees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring

Comment: arraycopy is the only common exception I can think of.

Comment: @PaulBoddington getenv as well, also in System.

Comment: String.subString would strike me as "Substitute String".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`camelCase` is used to separate words, substring is not to be intended as Sub String but as Substring... so the convention is respected.

Comment: Sorry, for this non-sense question. My bad.

Answer (score 10):

I'd say because substring is one physical word.